# Getting Incompatible types error while trying to map a list

Tags: java, list, mapping

I have a FeeAccount list that I would like to fill. I want to use .stream.map() to get it done. What I've managed to do is to make a method that would map my list and return it. I've written this code using some other examples I have found online. My problem is that somehow it returns a list that is incompatible with List.

I am getting an error: *Incompatible types. Required List but 'map' was inferred to Stream: no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Stream conforms to List*

As I understand the problem is with the part where I use *collect(Collectors.toList())*. But I am not sure. I don't even clearly understand what the error message means.

Maybe someone can explain what am I doing wrong? Is it with the .stream.map()? Because I never used it before. Or maybe the problem is somewhere else.

```
Method(List<contract> contractList){
 List<FeeAccount> feeAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

    feeAccounts = contractList
            .stream()
            .map(contract -> {

                List<Fee> monthlyFees=...;

                return monthlyFees.stream()
                        .map(monthlyFee -> {
                            FeeAccount account = new FeeAccount();
                            account.setFeeCode(monthlyFee.getFeeCode());
                            account.setDebtorAccount(contract.getDebtorAccount());
                            return account;
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            });}
```

Comment: You take a list. You stream it. You map each contract in it to a list. So you have a stream of lists. A stream of lists is not a list. Not sure what you really wanted to do because of the `...` part. Better [edit] the question and post a proper [mcve] instead.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the ... part is not important, just wanted to show that the monthlyFees list is somehow filled, that it's not null, sorry for misleading. I've got the answer now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two nested `map` operations. The outer transforms a `contract` to a `List<FeeAccount>`, and the inner transforms a `Fee` to a `FeeAccount`.

Hence, your pipeline results in a `Stream<List<FeeAccount>>` without a terminal operation.

If you add a `.collect(Collectors.toList())` in the end, you'll get a `List<List<FeeAccount>>`.

If you want to merge all those inner lists into a single output list, you should use `flatMap`.

To obtain a flat `List`:

```
List<FeeAccount> feeAccounts = 
    contractList.stream()
                .flatMap(contract -> {
                    List<Fee> monthlyFees=...;
                    return monthlyFees.stream()
                                      .map(monthlyFee -> {
                                          FeeAccount account = new FeeAccount();
                                          account.setFeeCode(monthlyFee.getFeeCode());
                                          account.setDebtorAccount(contract.getDebtorAccount());
                                          return account;
                                      });
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining every detail. I've managed to fix it, and now it works fine. I'll need to read more about flatMap and the difference between a usual map.

Answer (score 1):

`map()` is an intermediate operation in a stream pipeline (please look at [Stream operations and pipelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)), which means that it returns a stream.

```
feeAccounts = contractList
           .stream()
           .map(...) // result of this operation is Stream<<List<FeeAccount>> 
and not a List<FeeAccount>
```

You are missing a terminal operation like `.collect(Collectors.toList()` :

```
List<FeeAccount> feeAccounts = contractList
           .stream()
           .flatMap(monthlyFees -> monthlyFees.stream()
                        .map(monthlyFee -> {
                            FeeAccount account = new FeeAccount();
                            account.setFeeCode(monthlyFee.getFeeCode());
                            account.setDebtorAccount(contract.getDebtorAccount());
                            return account;
                        })
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) transforms `Stream<Stream<FeeAccount>>` into just `Stream<FeeAccount>`